# Grails - render validation errors as JSON

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.0

I'm building a RESTful API and the endpoints I'm creating are using command objects to validate the request data. I'm trying to figure out the best way to render the validation errors as json. For xml responses I followed the recommendation in the Grails in Action book and did...

```
response.status = 403
    render(contentType: "text/xml") {
        errors {
            eventSaleDataCommand.errors.fieldErrors.each { err ->
                field(err.field)
                    message(g.message(error: err))
                }
            }
        }
```

This works well for rendering xml responses so I'm wondering what the recommended approach for rendering json responses is?

I wanted to have some control of how the error gets displayed so for the json response I added:

```
def results = eventSaleDataCommand.errors.fieldErrors.toList()
def errors = []
for (error in results) {
    errors.add([
        'type'          : 'invalid_entry',
        'field'         : error.field,
        'rejected_value': error.rejectedValue,
        'message'       : error.defaultMessage
    ])
}
render errors as JSON
```

Problem with this approach is I'm using the Joda time plugin so I'm getting the following exception when I try to render the map as JSON:

`Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public".`

Anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: you have tried changing the contentType to `text/json`, haven't you?

Comment: Yes. I get an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Array elements must be defined with the "element" method call eg: element(value)`

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
render eventSaleDataCommand.errors.fieldErrors as JSON
```

Comment: The JSON output of this is incredibly verbose and cryptic for some really simple cases - like a unique constraint. I can't fit the example in this comment. It's over a thousand characters for a single unique constraint violation on a simple domain class complete with what looks like stack traces. I cannot recommend this approach.